# How to set HikariCP to readOnly for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hikaricp

I'm using Spring Boot and HikariCP and trying to set up a connection to a MySQL db to be read-only. But all attempts fail. I'm running Spring Boot 2.0.5 and HikariCP 3.2.0, and MySQL connector 8.0.11.

I've got 2 datasources - 1 is for write and the other for read. I've tried to set the property in my Spring Boot application.properties file, but the configuration shown in the *catalina.out* log shows that the readOnly setting is false.

I have a configuration class that uses the properties in the application.properties files to configure the pool, but can't seem to get it to change the *readOnly* property from `false` to `true`.
I also tried to put a `setReadOnly(true);` statement within the `dataSource()` method - didn't work.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "reader.datasource")
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory",
    basePackages = {"com.abc.data.reader.repo"})
public class ReaderDataSourceConfig extends HikariConfig {

@Bean(name = "readerDataSource")
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return new HikariDataSource(this);
}

@Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
        EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,@Qualifier("readerDataSource") 
DataSource dataSource) {
    return builder.dataSource(dataSource).packages("com.abc.repo")
            .persistenceUnit("reader")
            .build();
}

@Bean(name = "transactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

And the lines from the properties file:

```
#HikariCP Reader config
reader.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:mysql://...
reader.datasource.username=###
reader.datasource.password=#####
reader.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
reader.datasource.maximum-pool-size=10
reader.datasource.connection-timeout=60000
reader.datasource.max-lifetime=1800000
reader.datasource.minimum-idle=10
reader.datasource.validation-timeout=15000
reader.datasource.read-only=true         ***tried multiple variations***
reader.datasource.hikari.read-only=true      
reader.datasource.readOnly=true
reader.dataSource.cachePrepStmts=true
reader.dataSource.prepStmtCacheSize=250
reader.dataSource.prepStmtCacheSqlLimit=2048
reader.dataSource.useServerPrepStmts=true
reader.dataSource.useLocalSessionState=true
reader.dataSource.rewriteBatchedStatements=true
reader.dataSource.cacheResultSetMetadata=true
reader.dataSource.cacheServerConfiguration=true
reader.dataSource.elideSetAutoCommits=true
reader.dataSource.maintainTimeStats=false
reader.datasource.pool-name=ReaderPool
```

Is it not possible to set it through a property file?

Comment: Hikari doesn't have a readonly attribute.  Maybe the underlying datasource from MySQL had but you would need to set that through `reader.dataSource. dataSourceProperties`. Which goes actually for most of the properties on there (currently most of them aren't even used).

Comment: So I should add a reader.dataSource.dataSourceProperties.readOnly  to the properties file?

Comment: It wouldn't help as there is no read only property on the mysql datasource. So in short it cannot be done. You can make all your transactions readonly but that still is a hint and doesn't mean it actually does something.

Comment: Got it. I do have the transactions marked as readonly and I do see that it is setting and resetting the read-only flag. Was hoping that I could keep it from going through the extra action. Thank you!